# Getting started with JavaMe

Tags: java-me, nokia

I'm trying to make a very simple program run on my Nokia 5000.
On the Nokia website, there is a SDK (Series 40). I included this SDK in my IntelliJ project.
The problem is, when I try to run the helloWorld app on my phone, I get an error message.

(http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Hello_World_in_Java_ME)

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have created a MIDP 2.1 / CLDC 1.1 application?

For Series40 phones, I would definitely start with just MIDP 2.0 / CLDC 1.0

Otherwise post your jad file and your manifest file.